# How is the memory of a class handled in C++?

Tags: c++, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are objects stored in memory in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405112/how-are-objects-stored-in-memory-in-c)

For example a C++ class:

```
class A{
 int value;
 void addOne(){
  value++;
 }
}
```

Will an instance of class A be loaded like this [pseudo code]:

```
[identifier of A]
[this is int value]
[this is void addOne(void)][value++]
```

Or like this:

```
[members identifier of A]
[this is int value]
```

[functions identifier of A]
[this is void addOne(ref to member of A)][A.value++]
Second should use less memory on multiple instances of a class. Because the same functions are used for all instances. How is the memory handled in C++? Is it possible to change memory handling?

Comment: What do you mean "identifier of A"?  or "members identifier of A"?

Comment: Actually sorry, that wasn't a proper duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006504/c-data-alignment-member-order-inheritance/2007980#2007980

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking if the member functions are stored in the instances of the class?  No.  Each instance uses the same functions, with it's[the instance's] address passed as the hidden parameter `this`.

Comment: Pretty much this. I would also add a note saying that no class identifiers are found anywhere, unless you're calling typeid().

Comment: Yes this was my question. I thought I need to something like this by hand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about the memory layout of class A it is the same as having a struct A i.e. the integer value.  The 4 bytes (or whatever bytes for int for that platform).
Functions are **not** part of the memory layout e.g. as pointers stored in function or something similar, so they do not affect the size of the class.
If the class A though was polymorphic class the size would be different as it would contain also the pointer to vtable.

Answer (score 1):

The layout is actually more like this:

Class instance:

```
[this is int value]
```

Somewhere else:

```
[this is void addOne(ref to member of A)][A.value++]
```

That is, a class consists of (exactly) its member variables and its base classes, nothing more (unless your class contains virtual functions, in which case it also contains a virtual function table) – in particular no “identifier”.

Same for its functions, which are stored somewhere else entirely, and not once for each class instance. Furthermore, a function of a class doesn’t contain a reference to its class either, nor to its members. It is just a memory block of code (machine code statements). When calling the function, you are (basically) *jumping to that location after pushing a pointer to the class instance onto the call stack. The method can then access the instance (and thus its members) by accessing the pointer on the stack.

Comment: I meant it like this with the empty line. Should have wrote it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, on Randall' Hyde's Write Great Code Volume 2 (great book, read it if you have some free time) there's a section that speaks just about that. Briefly, a class holds variables just like `structs`, but it has a record which keeps pointers to functions declared in that class (VMT):

> VMT stands for virtual method table,
>   and these 4 bytes contain a pointer to
>   an array of “method pointers” for the
>   class. Virtual methods (also known as
>   virtual member functions in C++) are
>   special class-related functions that
>   you declare as fields in the class.
>   [...]
>   Calling a virtual member function
>   requires two indirect accesses. First,
>   the program has to fetch the VMT
>   pointer from the class object and use
>   that to indirectly fetch a particular
>   virtual function address from the VMT.
>   Then the program has to make an
>   indirect call to the virtual member
>   function via the pointer it
>   retrieved from the VMT.
>   [...]
>   For a given class there is only one
>   copy of the VMT in memory. This is a
>   static object so all objects of a
>   given class type share the same VMT.

Comment: This isn’t entirely correct. First, in C++ there is *no* difference between classes and structs in terms of memory layout. Secondly, the example in the question doesn’t have a vtable/VMT so this description is misleading.

Comment: @Konrad: I just copied from that book =P