# How the C++ complete object stored in memory

Tags: c++, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are objects stored in memory in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405112/how-are-objects-stored-in-memory-in-c)

Hello All,

I am improving the question a bit.
I was asked a c++ question about, how the c++ objects are stored in memory when created a object using stack memory and dynamic memory.

When object is created in heap, the automatic variables in class i.e like POD data types.
memory will be destroyed after deleting the object. or any different behavior ?

Please provide your comments.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/405112/1155650

Comment: Please give specific details to your request

Answer (score 0):

The best  I can find out quickly is [this one](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CHIQFjAH&url=http://www.idt.mdh.se/kurser/cd5130/msl/2005lp4/downloads/reports/c%2b%2b_object_model.pdf&ei=DjVoT8bsFM6mrAeZ-KiECA&usg=AFQjCNGvQvWVrEWmvC92ob8QsFxmrdWbqw&sig2=cvqVncHDUsyysBkiN0yRow), Have  a look in similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632600/memory-layout-c-objects). . . . Following is a pictorial representation of how class objects are stored in the memory,

In this example `small` is an object which contains the `labelObject`, 
[image]

Comment: as I search I see that their are so many similar questions here on SO... have a look on related questions here - - - >>>> "under the related link, at the bottom right of this page"..

Comment: I don't quite see what this is supposed to represent... a UML diagram perhaps ? It certainly does *not* look like anything C++ish.

Comment: Yes, this bears no relation to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This book will help - "Inside the C++ Object Model"

[http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Object-Model-Stanley-Lippman/dp/0201834545](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201834545)